# Calculate vertical jump air time

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

Hello im working with an app that are counting how many jumps you are making, im using gyroscope for this app to calculate the jumpings you are making. But the problem i have atm is that when i move the device slightly it counts as an jump, and that's not how i want it. I want it when ever it reaches an altitue it shal count as an jump.

```
int count = 0;
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    double d = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(2, event.values[0]) + Math.pow(2, event.values[1]) + Math.pow(2, event.values[2])) - 2);
    String result ="";

    if(d != 0){
        count++;
        result = String.valueOf(d/100.0);
    }
    text.setText("jump counts" + " " + count);
    text.invalidate();
    Log.i("Gyro", result);
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't use gyroscope for that. Gyroscopes are for measuring rotation. Use an accelerometer.
2. If you check whether there is any change (`d != 0`), it will catch any movement that is larger than the sensor's precision.

Comment: @StenSoft i tried it out with accelorometer and only used Y, and made on every shake it will count as an jump but sometimes it took more jump counts.

Comment: Accelerometers measures acceleration (`TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` linear which is what you want and `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` overall including gravity which you may want to use for older devices as a fallback). You also need time to get distance from it. And you need to compare it with a threshold to exclude small (non-jump) changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a threshold value for which a jump is counted if the gyro returns a distance greater than or equal to that threshold value.

```
int count = 0;

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        double d = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(2, event.values[0]) + Math.pow(2, event.values[1]) + Math.pow(2, event.values[2])) - 2);
        String result ="";
        SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        float threshold=preferences.getFloat(KEY,defaulttValue)
        if(d != 0 && d>=threshold){
            count++;
            result = String.valueOf(d/100.0);
        }
        text.setText("jump counts" + " " + count);
        text.invalidate();
        Log.i("Gyro", result);
    }
```

this threshold value can be calibrated by the user, stored in shared preferences so that it can be modified later.

Comment: I tested your code and it works great, but the problem now is that when i shake the phone example how you screw something or like balancing (left and right) it counts as a jump don't know if i can disable it or lower the sense of that.

Comment: Maybe you can check for the linear acceleration and measure the changes in the Y axis only, discard the X axis values that count into moving left or right. check this link for more info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-linear